# Compiling SCOL using gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation, environment-variables

I am compiling an ancient program called [SCOL](http://vinartus.net/spa/) (written in 1997) which comes pre-packged with [OpinionFinder](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/mpqa/opinionfinderrelease/) using gcc 3.4.5. I am using CentOS 5.5. After giving the make command, I get the following error:

```
/home/shahw/opinionfinder/software/scol1k/tools/tagfixes -c e8.fx
Wrote e8.fxc
/home/shahw/opinionfinder/software/scol1k/tools/tagfixes -c bnc.fx
Wrote bnc.fxc
env BIN=/home/shahw/scol//bin MAN=/home/shahw/scol//man LIB=/home/shahw/scol//lib ./mk.csh.rc
env: ./mk.csh.rc: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [csh.rc] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shahw/opinionfinder/software/scol1k/data'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I have confirmation from a source that the program compiles fine with this version of gcc, however I am not able to track down other platform specific information. Could this be an os specific problem? Do I need to set some environment variable for this to work? Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the file `mk.csh.rc` exist? In other words, is the problem that `make` can't find what actually exists, or is the file genuinely missing?

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong shell, e.g. you might need to use csh rather than bash ?

Comment: @jwd Looking into the directory which the compiler exits when it crashes. The directory does contain my.csh.rc.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a compiler error. This is a build system error. The issue seems to have nothing to do with gcc, at least as far as the output you've shown indicates.

Comment: Maybe try `chmod +x` on `mk.csh.rc` if it isn't already?

Comment: @Paul R . Yes! I needed to use the csh over just bash and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Shah W: OK - great - I'll convert my comment to an answer which you can then accept and then it might be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong shell. You're probably using `bash` whereas the old makefile seems to be assuming `csh` or similar. Try changing your shell to `csh` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find the file mk.csh.rc. Try finding this file first, using *find* command, and then you can include the directory in which this file resides by changing the environment variable *path* using *export* command